# Pesquisar intervalo de números (tipo string) com Expression Lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho esse modelo de dados e não sei como fazer a instrução *lambda*:

```
public class CidadeAbrangencia
    {
        [Key]
        public int CidadeAbrangencia_Id { get; set; }
        public string CEPInicial { get; set; }
        public string CEPFinal  { get; set; }
    }
```

Exemplo, preciso buscar todos os CEPs que iniciam em 03500-000 até 04000-000.

Consulta:

```
IEnumerable<CidadeAbrangencia> retAbrangencia = context.CidadeAbrangencias.Where(x => x.CEPInicial >= '03500-000' && '04000-000');
```

Meu problema é que o **CEP Inicial** e o **CEP Final** são tipos `string`, então como fazer?

Por ser String dá erro:

> O operador >= não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos string e sgtring

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O operador `>=` não funciona em strings em expressão lambda, talvez futuramente isso mude.

Para obter este comportamento você deve usar o método [CompareTo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads), acredito ser o mais próximo disto. Fiz com base nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553442/5429980) do SOen.

Veja o código:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {             
        var cidades = new List<CidadeAbrangencia> {
            new CidadeAbrangencia {
                CidadeAbrangencia_Id = 1,
                CEPInicial = "03500-001",
                CEPFinal = "04000-000"
            },
            new CidadeAbrangencia {
                CidadeAbrangencia_Id = 2,
                CEPInicial = "03500-002",
                CEPFinal = "03211-000"
            },
            new CidadeAbrangencia {
                CidadeAbrangencia_Id = 3,
                CEPInicial = "03500-005",
                CEPFinal = "05800-000"
            },
            new CidadeAbrangencia {
                CidadeAbrangencia_Id = 4,
                CEPInicial = "09211-011",
                CEPFinal = "99900-999"
            },
            new CidadeAbrangencia {
                CidadeAbrangencia_Id = 5,
                CEPInicial = "03500-021",
                CEPFinal = "04000-000"
            }
        };      
        var res = cidades.Where(x => x.CEPInicial.CompareTo("03500-000") >= 0 && x.CEPFinal.CompareTo("04000-000") <= 0).ToList();
        res.ForEach(c => WriteLine(c.CidadeAbrangencia_Id));        
    }
}
```

Saída

> 1
>   2
>   5

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bw2DfY).

Sugiro que você adapte este código e use com cuidado porque não fiz todos os testes.

Comment: vou implementar e testar daí posto aqui o resultado agradeço por enquanto.

Answer (score 7):

Se estiver tudo formatado corretamente poderia usar esta sintaxe, se entendi o que quer seria algo assim:

```
x => String.Compare(x.CEPInicial, "03500-000") >= 0 && String.Compare(x.CEPFinal, "04000-000") <= 0
```

Outra forma que deve funcionar:

```
x => x.CEPInicial.CompareTo("03500-000") >= 0 && x.CEPFinal.CompareTo("04000-000") <= 0
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/IsRange.cs).

Esses métodos fazem a comparação e retornam:

- -1 se o valor da esquerda for menor que o da direita
- 0 se os valores forem iguais
- 1 se o valor da esquerda for maior que o da direita

Documentação do [`CompareTo()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_String_CompareTo_System_String_) e [`Compare()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_).

Só depende de realmente ter todos os dígitos colocados corretamente. Se não estiver assim se torna extremamente complicado.

Quando a *string* tem os primeiros caracteres com grandeza maior que os seguintes a ordem pode ser estabelecida exatamente como se fizesse com número.

Porém, se estiver usando isso com Entity Framework, e a pergunta não diz sobre isto, mas dá indícios em um ponto, e dá indícios que não em outro (`IEnumerable<CidadeAbrangencia>`), poderá gerar uma consulta SQL bem confusa ou ter problemas. Mas pode ficar bom porque depende do *provider* ser muito bem feito para entender essas coisas.

Não garanto que o resultado será correto porque inclusive a pergunta não está clara qual seria a lógica disso, mas pelo menos funcionaria e resolveria o problema relatado.

Comment: Mas ocorre o erro de tipo de dados: O operador >= não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos string e sgtring

Comment: Eu edite o post e adicionei a mensagem de erro

Comment: Hein? Existe o operador `>=` para `string` e `string`?

Comment: Acho que esse operador `>=` não funciona para a String.

Comment: Exatamente @gato ! não funciona ! E como eu posso contornar esse problema ?

Comment: @LINQ oops, linguagem errada :D

Comment: @adrianojc Ou vc converte usando o `TryParse` (não acho uma boa ideia) ou terá que elaborar um método de extensão. Mas deve haver algo nativo para isso, tem que checar a documentação antes.

Comment: @Maniero Eu até fui procurar no C# 8 pra ver se tinha algo =D Provavelmente é Kotlin